# Slider image in div with preview

Tags: javascript, html

Starting from this slider, is it possible to have – on the right and left – previews of the images (with low opacity) that will go to the iphone (with high opacity) once the slider starts?

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  center: true,
  items: 1,
  loop: true,
  margin: 0
});
```

```css
.screen .item {
  background-color: #5fba7d;
}

.phone {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKQ2K.png);
  width: 320px !important;
  height: 650px;
  background-position: -25px 0;
}

.no-js .owl-carousel,
.owl-carousel.owl-loaded {
  position: relative;
  top: 48px;
  width: 278px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

.owl-stage-outer,
.owl-item,
.item {
  height: 100%;
}

.owl-stage {
  height: calc(100% - 153px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.green.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="phone">
  <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme screen">
    <div class="item">
      <h4>1</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h4>2</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h4>3</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h4>4</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h4>5</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
```

I found this old code, it should have result like this:

[image]

Where is the "Take a closer look" section

Comment: "*it should have result like this...*" - what result would that be; there's a lot of page there and I didn't see anything that resembles a carousel or image slider?

Comment: @DavidThomas I updated by posting a photo

Comment: Thank you for the update :) could you clarify - in your question - what you've tried to do to solve this problem? You've clearly "found code," but how have you attempted to tailor that code to your requirements? What - if any - problems did you encounter?

Comment: @DavidThomas i tried to add to iphone
    position: relative;
     overflow: hidden;

  and modify the css classes

.owl-carousel {
     position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
     tops: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
   }

   .owl-item {
     opacity: 0;
     transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
     displays: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
   }

   .owl-item.active {
     opacity: 1;
   }

then in the js i tried to add and remove two classes "preview" and "next"